# Цена выраст?т

Tags: орфография

как правильно пишется "цена вырастИт" или "цена вырастЕт"????

Comment: Цена вырастет. От вырасти - 1-ое спряжение. 

Сравните: Он скоро вырастет (вырасти - 1 спр.). - Он вырастит хороший урожай (вырастить - 2 спр.).

Comment: >От вырасти - 1-ое спряжение. 

Правильная цена вырастит спрос.)))

Answer (score 2):

Если речь о том, что цена возрастет, то ***"Цена вырастет"***. 
"Цена вырастит  (кого, чего)" - это другой смысл, всерьез я его, правда,  не рассматриваю, но чем черт не шутит.

Answer (score 2):

Если цена водки выраст**е**т сверх всякой меры, её цена выраст**и**т новое поколение самогонщиков.

Comment: цена меры?